# No colored icons inside 'more' of UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I get colored tab icons for the tabs as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

but when I click more and view further tabs, I don't get colored tab icons

[image]

How to get colored tab icons for 'more' tabs? Here's my code in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UITabBar *tb = tabBarControllerProperty.tabBar;
        NSArray *itemsObject = tb.items;
        for(UITabBarItem *tabItem in itemsObject)
        {
            UIImage *imaged = tabItem.image;
            if([imaged respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)])
            {
                tabItem.image = [imaged imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            }
            else
            {
                tabItem.image = imaged;
            }
            tabItem.selectedImage = imaged;

        }
```

Comment: do you want to set image on more item ??

Comment: no.. i want to set colored image icons i get after clicking 'more'. Refer 2nd screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For setting selection indicator:

```
[[yourTabBarController tabBar] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:ImageName]];
```

For setting tab bar icons use the following code:

```
yourTabBarController.ViewController[0].tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:TitleForTabItem image:[[UIImage imageNamed:FirstTabIconImage] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:FirstTabIconImage]];
```

Using this set tab bar item for other viewControllers also.

go on... :)

Comment: how to set colored icons and give image name for 'startnew' 'contacts' and 'logout'? Refer 2nd screenshot. I added [self.tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img6.png"]]; in class's initWithNibName and also tried in appDelegate.

Comment: You can use the same tab bar icons. And need to create a selection indicator image for your tab bar. And then set that selection indicator image as above.

Comment: following code in appdelegate is not working 
if(self.tabBarControllerProperty.selectedIndex == 4)
    {
        [self.tabBarControllerProperty.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"collaborations.png"]];
    }
    if(self.tabBarControllerProperty.selectedIndex == 5)
    {
        [self.tabBarControllerProperty.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contacts.png"]];
    }
    if(self.tabBarControllerProperty.selectedIndex == 6)
    {
        [self.tabBarControllerProperty.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"]];
    }

Comment: Use the selection indicator only once. And set your tab bar images separately.